# How to estimate ECL through monte carlo simulation?

Tags: statistics, finance, monte-carlo, simulation, copula

I am trying to run a montecarlo simulation based on [this](https://www.openriskmanual.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_Simulation_of_Credit_Portfolios) model in order to assess whether a loan/company will default or not. Basically the model is

$$X_i = \sqrt{1-\rho}Z_i + \sqrt{\rho} Y$$

where $$ Z_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1) $$ represents the credit $i$ and $$ Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1) $$
$Z_i$ are independent of each other and of the common factor $Y$.

The time to maturity for each credit is divided in year and for each each year I have generated $10.000$ variables for $Z$ and $10.000$ variables for $Y$ and then combined them to get the value for $X$. So for each year I have $10.000$ values of X and from this the model says that I have to assess whether a default has occured or not. This is done by comparing the result with a predefined threshold value of (historical) default rate $a$ as follows

$$\Phi(X_i) < a $$
So if $\Phi(X_i) < a $ then we have a default, otherwise not. I am very unsure about this part and here is where I am lost and do not know how to proceed. What I do not understand is $what$ is it that I am supposed to compare with the threshold value?

Have I misunderstood the model? Is the simulation run correctly?

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: You have $X_i \sim \mathcal(0,1)$ too so I would guess that $U_i$ can stand for $X_i$.  But generating $10000$ different values of $Y$ rather defeats the point of the model.  I would have thought that you should use the same macro risk $Y$ for all the specific $Z_i$ in a particular year: multiple values of $Y$ would represent different years.

Comment: Of course I meant $\Phi(X_i)$. Thanks for the correction. Moreover I do use the same $Y$ but I was not clear enough. Thanks for pointing out that. But regarding my direct questions, do you have any suggestions on how I should proceed after the simulations?